# FATAL: Cookbook file has a ruby syntax error. How to find error information?

Tags: chef-infra

I understand that cookbook has a syntax error:

> FATAL: Cookbook file has a ruby syntax error.

How to find detailed information on the error using knife tool upload command

`knife upload cookbooks/wso2-* --force -V
INFO: Using configuration from knife.rb
INFO: Validating ruby files
INFO: Validating templates
INFO: Syntax OK
INFO: Saving wso2-analytics
INFO: Uploading files
INFO: Upload complete!
Updated cookbooks/wso2-analytics
INFO: Validating ruby files
INFO: Validating templates
INFO: Syntax OK
INFO: Saving wso2-apim
INFO: Uploading files
INFO: Upload complete!
Updated cookbooks/wso2-apim
INFO: Validating ruby files
FATAL: Cookbook file  has a ruby syntax error:`

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not getting those information as described in that question thats the problem. I am simply getting above error.

Comment: Are you saying that adding the verbose flag did not give you any useful information?

Comment: yes exactly. @AndrewMorton Is there any where I can find the logs ?

Comment: Does `-VV` ("very verbose," I suppose) give any useful information?

Comment: Thanks got some information @AndrewMorton. were able to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It might be that using the `config_log_level` option in [knife.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html) would also help. Maybe you could make an answer with how you solved the problem and then accept it, so that this question has a conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below command to get more verbose information using `-VV` command

```
knife upload cookbooks/cookbookname -VV
```

Thanks @AndrewMorton for providing right solution to debug the problem.

Also **knife.rb** file contains below information

```
$cat .chef/knife.rb

base_dir = File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '..')
log_level     :info
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trace this down by using the following arguments when attempting upload your cookbook:

```
knife cookbook upload cookbook_name -VVV
```

It will tell you which file the upload attempt is failing on.

Hope this helps!